# How can I access document folder

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, itunes

I have redirected all logs to file in the app's document folder. I know how to access it trough the xcode. I have to plug my ipad to MAC and in the xcode through organizer->device i can access the document folder. Now I want to do it without xcode. Can i access my log files through itunes or device it self.

Comment: you could access to you device using the [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) _(freeware)_ desktop application, without any complication if the device is connected to your MAC via USB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can access your data through itunes.

For this first you need to add a new key, `UIFileSharingEnabled` to your info.plist. From the drop down list select "Application supports iTunes file sharing" and select the check box against that.

[image: UIFileSharingEnabled]

When you sync your ipad with itunes, go to your ipad -> select your app.
You will see the data in from your application.

Comment: If you're finding this, now it's called _Application supports iTunes file sharing_.

Answer (score 1):

Would would need to set your app to [enable file sharing through iTunes](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app). Step 5 looks like the only thing you'd need to do to get it working.