# IPhone: Best way to deliver configuration file to test application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, itunes-app

### Main Problem

I have to write test application for iOS to test very complex multi platform framework.
There are already applications for other platforms which are using common configuration file (which defines test servers, user names, log level, and so on). Configuration process is quite complex so providing a complex UI will be waste of time on mobile platforms.

1. This file is a `xml` and its file name extension is `xml`.
2. Tester will have multiple configuration files (will use only one at the time)
3. This files should be easily uploaded by tester
4. tester should be able to select configuration file

### What solution I'm looking for

At bagging I was thinking about iCloud service. Problem is that in 90% of cases device is shared by multiple people (testers and developers), so I'm not convinced this is best approach, since this will provide problems with sharing an iCloud account (usually there is account per device not per tester/project).

It would be best if this files could be delivered to application by using iTunes. Anyone who will do test will have this tool to install test application, so it would be nice if he could upload those files too.

Any useful hint will be appreciated (not necessary a full solution).

As a bonus opposite direction would be also useful (fetching logs). Currently usually logs are send by an email. If it is possible to easily fetch this in same meaner as configuration file it would be great.

---

Ok looks like it is possible to do this with iTunes.
When inspecting list of installed app for device in iTunes at the bottom there is a section "File Sharing" where you can add remove files.

Comment: whoever posted a "close vote". This is not opinion based or looking for a book. I'm looking for specific software solution related to software testing, so your "close vote" IMO doesn't make seance here.

Comment: Is it require that your test application for iOS, test something by readying XML File and there are differant XML files that testers wants to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've finally found [something like that](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app). This perfectly solves my problem.

Files will be uploaded and downloaded by iTunes.

[Another helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546424/1387438).

Answer (score 0):

If you want

1. That your test application for iOS, test something by readying XML File
2. There are different XML files
3. There are different testers.

In this case rather than doing too much you can

1. Ask testers to upload the files in dropbox.
2. Have a textbox in your app, in which user will type the URL of XML file (which they have uploaded on dropbox)
3. And next to it you have test button on click of it you can download the file and test against the logic.
4. Once the test is over you can grab the result by email or ask them to upload on Dropbox (manually or using api).